# Wine Calling Linux code from DLL

Tags: linux, windows, dll, wine

I've got an utility (no source code avaliable) which is uses NTCAN.dll (dll comes with driver for ESD PCI CAN cards) to communicate via CAN. I want to use it in Linux which have a very similar library. I can recompile NTCAN.dll because i know all exported function names and signatures. The question is how to use linux native code from DLL using WINE?

Comment: With the detail provided, well the lack of it, there's little we can say that is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem, as the DLL likely does some DeviceIoControl calls to its company driver. So you will have to reverse the driver too. Have you tried to ask the manufacturer of the card, they should be interested to sell it to customers with Linux.

See:

- [Dropping Windows with WineLib](http://www.drdobbs.com/dropping-windows-with-winelib/184401635)
- [Winelib User's Guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User%27s_Guide)

Comment: You absolutelly right. And in fact ESD delivers linux driver and library (.so with same functions signatures) but how can i use this .so instead of .dll when i have no source code for original exetutable file?

Comment: And i have a posibility to rewrite dll (because i know exports and it's signatures) but i have no idea how to call Linux native code from this rewrited dll.

Comment: Ok so you can rewrite the DLL as a wrapper around their native Linux .so which calls their native driver. The DLL won't call directly the driver.

Comment: i want to. But how? Can you show me example or something?

Comment: Ah. My bad. I haven't thought about this. Can you ask a specific question about this, like: how to call  a .so library from Windows-style code under Wine?  Otherwise you'll have to make some kind of client-server pair, that looks like overkill.

Comment: i'm already implement client server UDP realization, but it has a huge (hugreds of microseconds) delays, because of that i've decide to solve problem in another way. I think for now i could formalize my question excactly as "How to call .so code from windows dll under Wine (or in Linux generally)"?

Comment: You are going to use Wine anyway, see if this article can help: http://www.drdobbs.com/dropping-windows-with-winelib/184401635

Comment: thanks. It's userful, but not exaclly that i need. I have rewrited ntcan.dll with methods like canOpen() canSend() canWrite() and have a .so file which contains real Linux implementations. And all i need it's just a call it in this way

canOpen(arg1,arg2){
return dotsocanOpen(arg1,arg2)
}
etc..

Comment: Can you get source of the .so?

Comment: i can rewrite it. Because i know how this .so interract with hardware

Comment: There should be tools in Wine to compile native Linux code which calls native Linux reads, writes, ioctls, and link it into a DLL callable by Windows app. But I don't know details.

Comment: Thanks, i found something interesting https://www.winehq.org/docs/winelib-guide/winelib-getting-started